# C# & SQL Server stored procedure multiple insert actions, influence?

Tags: c#, sql-server

I have an application which uses stored procedures to insert datatables into my SQL Server. At run-time, it will access the database, uses the one stored procedure and one table to do several insert actions. But how does it affect my database?

For example I have

- 5 Datatables (dt1..dt5)
- 1 Table (tb1)
- 1 stored procedure

At run-time all dt's were processed in its own task.

Each task does a few data manipulation and finally store them into SQL Server via a stored procedure into table `tb1`.

But what is the influence if I do something like that? Will these datatables append after another?

Here some code:

```
public static void CreateTasks(string sInput, string sOutput)
{          
    List<Task> Tasks = new List<Task>();
    string Filename = Path.GetFileName(sInput).Replace(" ", "_").Replace("\\", "_");            
    ...

    // Stores datatable via stored procedure into SQL Server
    Tasks.Add(Task.Factory.StartNew(() => StoreDataInSQL(sInput, sOutput, Filename)));            
    ...

    Task.WaitAll(Tasks.ToArray());
}
```

Comment: Without some code to view we are completely in the dark...

Comment: Why do you need a code if I am asking for influence in general?

Comment: Because the answer as it stands is "It depends on what your code does"

Comment: Okay I was just asking because I was curious.
Added some code, not a reason to downvote..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My interpretation of what your question is asking: "what happens when you concurrently execute/make multiple changes to the same table".

The answer: it depends .... on great many things, not least of which is what (and how) your SP code works.

In the case of simple inserts: it will append all of your inserts.

This looks like a good article on table locking and transactions: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/sql-server-transaction-locking-and-row-versioning-guide?view=sql-server-2017